# Different html/css for first 4 posts in the same query in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to change the HTML structure and CSS styles of the first 4 posts in the main WP_Query in `archive.php`

I am doing this simple thing where I checked the global `$wp_query` variable.

```
if ( have_posts() ) :

  if( 4 > $wp_query->current_post ) :
    the_title();
  endif;

  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

  endwhile;

  else :

  get_template_part( 'no-results', 'archive' );

endif;
```

This works fine, the first 4 posts in the query get displayed in whatever HTML/CSS I apply to them before the `get_template_part()` gets called in.

The problem is when I go to the next page in the pagination, a different set of 4 posts get displayed. The 4 new posts of the second page in the pagination.

I don't want that. I want the same 4 posts that appear on the first page to keep appearing as I go to the next or previous pages. I need to give the first 4 posts a different HTML structure, not just CSS styling and I need them to persist throughout the pagination.

I tried changing the main query with `pre_get_posts` and using `offset` but that gave me a set of problems in the theme and the admin panel that I decided against it.

How may I achieve that?

**EDIT** My first attempt at this problem was to do a second query and leave the main query intact but then I wouldn't be able to check the `post_count` in the first query to see if it's bigger than 4 because I'm always showing only 4 `posts_per_page` that's why I need them to be in the same query because I'm going to hide the first 4 posts on the category page that doesn't have more than 4 posts and only show them on the category page that has more than 4 posts.

**EDIT 2** To make this simpler to understand, if it's getting too messy.

```
IF CATEGORY (QUERY) HAS MORE THAN 4 POSTS

    DISPLAY 4 POSTS WITH CUSTOM HTML/CSS

    THEN GET TEMPLATE PART AND DISPLAY THE REST OF THE POSTS WHILE EXCLUDING THE FIRST 4 POSTS BECAUSE DUPLICATES

ELSE

    DISPLAY DEFAULT TEMPLATE PART
```

Comment: For the first four posts try a new query for that loop to break it out of the pagination/archive loop: <?php $rp_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=4' ); and then run a new loop (keep the original loop in archive intact).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a loop I use to show the first four posts, it has a wp_reset_postdata that might be required so your pagination loop is unaffected.

```
<?php $rp_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=4' );
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $rp_query->have_posts() ) : $rp_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <? endif; ?>
```

Comment: My first attempt at this problem was to do a second query and leave the main one intact but then I wouldn't be able to check the `post_count` in the first query to see if it's bigger than 4 because I'm always showing only 4 `posts_per_page` that's why I need them to be in the same query because I'm going to hide it on the category page that doesn't have more than 4 posts.

Comment: This is a tough one!

Answer (score -1):

Solution is already built-in and available as plugin.
Please try Blog Designer PRO plugin - https://codecanyon.net/item/blog-designer-pro-for-wordpress/17069678?ref=miyanialkesh7

Best regards,
Alkesh